# Proof about triangle inequality

Tags: complex-analysis, algebra-precalculus

Follow the steps bellow to give an algebraic derivation of the triangle inequality

$$|z_1+z_2| \leq |z_1|+|z_2|$$

a) Show that $$|z_1+z_2|^2=(z_1+z_2)(\overline{z_1}+\overline{z_2})=z_1\overline{z_1}+(z_1 \overline{z_2}+\overline{z_1 \overline{z_2}})+z_2 \overline{z_2}$$

b) Point out why $$z_1 \overline{z_2}+\overline{z_1 \overline{z_2}}=2Re(z_1 \overline{z_2}) \leq 2|z_1||z_2|$$

c) Use the results in parts a and b to obtain the triangle inequality

Approach: Part a is easy. Just use the properties of complex conjugates.

For part b, I used algebra. I don't know if there is trick to do this. I basically set $z_1=x+yi$ and $z_2=a+bi$, so $(2Re(z_1\overline{z_2}))^2=4(xa+yb)^2$ and $(2|z_1||z_2|)^2=4(x^2a^2+x^2b^2+y^2a^2+y^2b^2)$. Now we just have to compare $2xayb$ vs $x^2b^2+y^2a^2$ and it turns out that $2xayb \leq x^2b^2+y^2a^2$
 because $(xb-ya)^2 \geq 0$, so part b holds

c) I don't know how to do this part

Comment: Part (c) is super easy if you use the results in (a) and (b) and the fact that $z\bar{z}=|z|^2$

Answer (score 1):

$$\vert z_1 + z_2 \vert^2= z_1\overline{z_1}+(z_1 \overline{z_2}+\overline{z_1 \overline{z_2}})+z_2 \overline{z_2} \leq  \vert z_1 \vert^2 + 2 \vert z_1\vert \, \vert z_2\vert + \vert z_2 \vert^2 = (\vert z_1 \vert + \vert z_2 \vert)^2$$

so taking square roots we get the inequality. As the comment says, the extra thing is that $z \overline{z}= \vert z \vert^2$